# Rollup TypeScript Configuration Produces Incomplete JavaScript Bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollupjs

I am building a React component library using Rollup and TypeScript, and I want to bundle the components so that others on my team can use them in their applications. The problem is my bundle output is missing exports, so my configuration is obviously flawed.

Rollup config:

```
export default {
    input: ['src/Button.tsx'],
    output: {
        dir: 'build',
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
        exports: 'named'
    },
    plugins: [
        typescript({
            declarationDir: 'build',
            jsx: 'react'
        }),
        sourceMaps()
    ]
};
```

TypeScript config:

```
{
  "include": [
    "src",
    "types"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "importHelpers": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@": [
        "./"
      ],
      "*": [
        "src/*",
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    },
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

And finally `Button.tsx`:

```
export enum ButtonSize {
...    
}

export enum ButtonType {
...    
}

const someVar = ...

interface ButtonProps {
...    
}

interface ButtonStyle {
...    
}

const buttonStyle: ButtonStyle = {
...
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = (p: ButtonProps) => {
...
}

export default Button
```

The final JavaScript bundle only has everything down to `someVar`. Everything *below* `someVar` is missing.

What is it about my configuration and code that leaves these gaps in the JavaScript output?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The default export `Button` is being lost, but other exports from this file are making it into the bundle? If you move `const someVar` to a different spot, does that change what gets exported?

Comment: You're telling me. Anyway, with tree shaking off, moving `someVar` doesn't change anything--meaning it's there. I should note in real life `someVar` makes reference to the values in `ButtonType` FWIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the answer was to eliminate all the `export default`. Simply exporting as named exports resolved the issue.

The reason?

"Note: default exports cannot be combined and exported by this plugin. Only named exports will be exported."

Which is in the fine print of `@rollup/plugin-multi-entry`